# scala-js unexpected checks resulting to undefined behavior

Tags: scala, scala.js

Running the following Scala code compiled into scala-js version 0.8.0, I get the following error:
`An undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of java.lang.String`

```
trait MyDataType extends js.Any {
  var wordy: String = js.native
}
// This usually comes from the backend.
val dataStruct = js.Dynamic.literal().asInstanceOf[MyDataType]
val isWordy = dataStruct.wordy
```

#### [Scala-js fiddle (press CTRL+ENTER)](http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/gist/f9de8b5fe4583a933c57?)

After investigation, the code above is compiled as:

```
var dataStruct = {};
var isWordy  = $as_T(dataStruct["wordy"]); // Line causing problem.
```

Obviously it is because of this `$as_T` which causes this trouble.
How can I make sure that the code above is unchecked ?

**Edit** I found a workaround which is not very elegant.

```
val isWordy = dataStruct.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].wordy
```

But still, why this `$as_T` ?

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is the wrong way around. Saying `asInstanceOf[MyDataType]` is *telling* Scala to typecheck it. That's almost exactly what that means. And when it typechecks, it typechecks completely: you are telling Scala.js that this *is* an instance of MyDataType, and therefore it must completely conform to MyDataType.

So if you really don't want it type-checked, the correct solution is simply to leave off the `asInstanceOf`. At that point it's a JavaScript dynamic, and you can do essentially anything with it.

(Or you need to assign something to `wordy` inside of `literal()`, so that it *is* actually `MyDataType`.)

In other words, Scala.js has its feet in two worlds: the untyped JavaScript and the strongly-typed Scala. Both work well, but at any given time you have to choose which one you're operating in.

**ETA:** a bit of rationale. The whole point of a strongly typed language is that everything in the code knows, with certainty, what the *structure* of the type is -- that way, you only have to worry about bugs in your code, not bad data. That's why `asInstanceOf` needs to be hard-assed: so that, if you pass the value to some function that expects `MyDataType`, it knows for certain that `wordy` is defined.

Comment: In addition, an alternative solution to your problem is to fix `MyDataType` so that it encodes the fact that `wordy` might not be there. To do this, type it as `var wordy: js.UndefOr[String]`. In that case, your test becomes `val isWordy = dataStruct.wordy.isDefined`.

Comment: Thank you Seb, that's exactly what I was looking for.